# How do I normalize a survey site's database?

Tags: mysql, database, database-normalization

I am trying to make a survey site, but I have not been able to normalize the database. I do not know how to correlate questions and answers in the database. There is a very strong relationship between questionnaire and questionnaire. Because I have the `QuestionID` in the question table as the primary Key, the `ID` numbers of the question numbers are unique. This is how the answer table works. How am I supposed to do that?

```
┌────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│     Member     │   Survey    │  Question  │   Choice   │   Category   │
├────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│ ID             │ SurveyID    │ QuestionID │ ChoiceID   │ ID           │
│ FirstName      │ SurveyorID  │ Question   │ Choice     │ CategoryName │
│ LastName       │ SurveyTitle │ SurveyID   │ QuestionID │              │
│ Mail           │ CategoryID  │            │            │              │
│ Password       │             │            │            │              │
│ NumberOfSurvey │             │            │            │              │
└────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Comment: You need to add a QuestionId to your Answer table and use a Composite key for that table with the combination of (question id, answer id) as the primary key. There is no need for Survey id in answer table.

Comment: A side note, you need to be consistent with your naming. The primary key for the `Member` and `Category` tables is `ID`, but the other tables are different. Change the primary key for all of them to be `ID` or all of them to be the same format.

Comment: We cannot help you with the design without knowing the relationships between your entities. Describe those relationships so we can give you the best solution that fits your needs, not a general solution that may not be the best fit. For example, what's the relationship between the member and surveys? How many surveys can a member have? How many surveys in each category? etc...

Comment: Please read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework'. Reference or quote your textbook--what defintions & process you are using--& show your work following it. Explain about why & how you are stuck. See my comments on many recent [tag:database-normalization] questions. We are not here to rewrite your textbook or do your homework. PS Use text, not links or images.

Answer (score 0):

I have come up with a structure which might work for your case with few or no modifications. The database structure is in the [Image](https://ibb.co/cvXYhH) attached. All the columns marked with * are the ones that are to be set as a primary key. If you are not sure of how to set multiple columns as primary keys, please refer [Composite Keys](https://www.javatpoint.com/sql-composite-key).

```
┌────────────────┬─────────────┬────────────┬────────────┬──────────────┐
│     Member     │   Survey    │  Question  │   Choice   │   Category   │
├────────────────┼─────────────┼────────────┼────────────┼──────────────┤
│ MemberID*      │ SurveyID*   │ QuestionID*│ ChoiceID*  │ CategoryID*  │
│ FirstName      │ MemberID*   │ Question   │ Choice     │ CategoryName │
│ LastName       │ SurveyTitle │ SurveyID*  │ QuestionID*│              │
│ Mail           │ CategoryID* │            │            │              │
│ Password       │             │            │            │              │
│ NumberOfSurvey │             │            │            │              │
└────────────────┴─────────────┴────────────┴────────────┴──────────────┘
```

Good Luck!

Comment: Why would you have a dedicated key column in the `Survey`, `Question`, and `Choice` tables and then make them part of composite keys? That makes no sense. The composite keys are usually all secondary keys or can include a column that has grouped values (e.g. language). A column that has all unique values should be a primary key by itself alone, not part of a composite key.

Comment: Having dedicated key columns help in faster querying. Composite keys can be a group of different columns and I don't see a problem with that!

Comment: For example, if each member can only have one survey per category, then the `MemberID` and `CategoryID` can be a composite key in the `Survey` table, and no need for the `SurveyID` at all.

Comment: This example is just an assumption and similarly, each member can have multiple surveys in multiple categories.

Comment: @Neels I know how to add more than one primary key. But why should we do more than one thing? For example SurveyID: 1 QuestionID: 1 data is entered. Then I enter data again. SurveyID: 1 QuestionID: 2. This data entry is not accepted because SurveyID is unique. It will not work.

Comment: Yes, but then you have a different design. You shouldn't have one design that fits all. Your design must depend on what you need. And your point about faster querying makes no sense. Again, you can make the `SurveyID` as the key alone and the other two can simply be secondary keys. That satisfies your scenario (multiple survey in each category) and no need for a composite key. What's your goal from the composite key in that scenario?

Comment: @BilalGünaydın If you define it as a composite key, this insert will work. The combination has to be unique, not the individual elements.

Comment: @RacilHilan I agree with you. This is just an idea that I came up with, with no knowledge of the business scenario. From my experience, no data models are perfect in the first go and change with time as requirements become more clear and broad.

Comment: @RacilHilan And secondary keys is something I have been using all my professional life. It makes sense to maintain that kind of code when you have large databases. WIth a small application, I personally think it will be less maintenance to not have secondary keys created.

Comment: @Neels I will use 1 category data for 1 survey. When I enter more than one query on the same questionnaire, I want the data attempt not to be blocked because of the ID. I entered data in SurveyID: 1 and QuestionID: 1. Then I enter the data when the data is SurveyID: 1 and the primary key is unique. The primary key will not allow this. I need another alternate. But I do not know.

Comment: @BilalGünaydın Have you created the schema and tried the inserts?

Comment: Hmmm, that's one approach, the incremental approach. It's a good approach in some cases when the business requirements are not clear and need sometime to be gathered, but we don't want to halt the development until all requirement are gathered. As for the secondary keys and smaller applications, I've had an experience similar to yours, so I agree :).

Comment: @Neels I made the shot. I tried to enter data. But it did not happen as I wanted.

Comment: @BilalGünaydın It would help if you can post your create scripts!

Comment: @Neels A questionnaire will have more than one question. In Tabloda this SurveyID: 1 1 requires a method to allow more than one data entry.

Comment: I think we are not on the same page, I have suggested a solution that would work for a simple MySQL database. If you are using any other 3rd party tool, then I am not sure if I can be of much help!

Comment: Please don't answer unclear questions, ask for clarification in comments on the question.